# I have 5 drop down menus but i need to change the next one according to what the user selects in the first one using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i have 5 drop down menus.  I need to fill the other options depending on what the user selects in the 1st or 2nd option. Here is my javascript so far,  trying to get or example. case 2 rod stewart: If the user chooses manchester show these dates and if user uses glasgow show these dates.

```
function fillVenue()
{
//clears dropdowns and price
venue.options.length=0;

//retrieves index of selected artist and target element to be populated
var artist=document.getElementById("artist").selectedIndex
var v=document.getElementById("venue");
var d=document.getElementById("date");
var t=document.getElementById("tickets");
var p=document.getElementById("price");


//switch statements fill target with artist array
switch (artist)
{
    case 1:  // madonna
    var arr=new Array ("Select Venue", "London");       
    fillList(arr,v);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Date", "17th July", "18th July");        
    fillList(arr,d);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");     
    fillList(arr,t);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70");        
    fillList(arr,p);
    break;

    case 2: //Rod Stewart
    var arr=new Array ("Select Venue", "Manchester", "Glasgow");
    fillList(arr, v);

    if (arr === "Manchester")
    {
        var arr=new Array ("Select Date", "18th July", "20th July");                    
        fillList(arr,d);


    }
    else if(arr === "Glasgow")
    {
        var arr=new Array ("Select Date", "22nd July", "23rd July");        
        fillList(arr,d);
    }

    var arr=new Array ("Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");     
    fillList(arr,t);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70");        
    fillList(arr,p);
    break;

    case 3: //Guns and Roses
    var arr= new Array ("Select Venue", "London");
    fillList(arr,v);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Date", "10th July");     
    fillList(arr,d);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");     
    fillList(arr,t);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Price", "£88");      
    fillList(arr,p);
    break;

    case 4: // Oasis
    var arr= new Array ("Select Venue", "London", "Glasgow", "Nottingham");
    fillList(arr,v);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Date");      
    fillList(arr,d);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");     
    fillList(arr,t);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Price");     
    fillList(arr,p);
    break;

    case 5: //Beyonce
    var arr= new Array ("Select Venue", "Glasgow", "Manchester", "Birmingham", "London");
    fillList(arr,v);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Date");      
    fillList(arr,d);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");     
    fillList(arr,t);
    var arr=new Array ("Select Price");     
    fillList(arr,p);

    break;
}

}



function fillList(arr,v)
{
    v.options.length=0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        option=new Option(arr[i], arr[i]);
        v.options[i] = option;
    }   
}
function fillList(arr,d)
{
d.options.length=0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        option=new Option(arr[i], arr[i]);
        d.options[i] = option;
    }   
}
    function fillList(arr,t)
    {
    t.options.length=0;
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
        option=new Option(arr[i], arr[i]);
        t.options[i] = option;
        }   
        }
function fillList(arr,p)
{
p.options.length=0;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        option=new Option(arr[i], arr[i]);
        p.options[i] = option;
    }   
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="contact">  

 <h2>Select your tickets</h2>

<select name="artist" id="artist" onChange="fillVenue()">
    <option>Select an Artist</option>
    <option value="madonna">Madonna</option>
    <option value="rodStewart">Rod Stewart</option>
    <option value="gunsAndRoses">Guns And Roses</option>
    <option value="oasis">Oasis</option>
    <option value="beyonce">Beyoncé</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<select name="venue" id="venue" style="width:120px">
<option>Select Venue</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select name="date" id="date" style="width:120px">
<option>Select Date</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select name="tickets" id="tickets" style="width:120px">
<option>Select Tickets</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select name="price" id="price" style="width:120px"> 
<option>Select Price</option>
<br><br>
```

***Customers buying four or more tickets will pay an additional £10 fee.**

Comment: What you want is a cascading drop down, do some research on them. Also, dont forget to actually include your code ;)

Comment: Check my updated answer.. see the new fiddle created.

Comment: did you check this fiddle ?? http://jsfiddle.net/paXz9/1/ . it is populating other dropdowns on user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded only the Rod Stewart part. You have empty arrays on Oasis and Beyonce. I suppose you want to do the same thing with them. You can use the same method.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2A77/2/)

```
function fillVenue() {

    //retrieves index of selected artist and target element to be populated
    var artist  = document.getElementById("artist");
    var venue   = document.getElementById("venue");
    var date    = document.getElementById("date");
    var ticket  = document.getElementById("tickets");
    var price   = document.getElementById("price");

    //clears dropdowns and price
    venue.options.length = 0;
    date.options.length = 0;
    ticket.options.length = 0;
    price.options.length = 0;

    // clearing the onchange event on venue
    venue.onchange = null;

    //switch statements fill target with artist array
    switch (artist.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);
            break;
        case 1:
            // madonna
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date", "17th July", "18th July"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);
            break;
        case 2:
            //Rod Stewart
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "Manchester", "Glasgow"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"]
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price", "£30", "£45", "£70"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);

            // adding onchange event on venue when the user selects rod stewart
            venue.onchange = function () {
                var dateList;
                switch(venue.selectedIndex) {
                    case 0: dateList = ["Select Date"]; break;
                    case 1: dateList = ["Select Date", "18th July", "20th July"]; break;
                    case 2: dateList = ["Select Date", "22nd July", "23rd July"]; break;
                }
                fillList(date, dateList);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            //Guns and Roses
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date", "10th July"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price", "£88"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);
            break;

        case 4:
            // Oasis
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "London", "Glasgow", "Nottingham"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);
            break;

        case 5:
            //Beyonce
            var venueList   = ["Select Venue", "Glasgow", "Manchester", "Birmingham", "London"];
            var dateList    = ["Select Date"];
            var ticketList  = ["Select Tickets", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
            var priceList   = ["Select Price"];
            fillList(venue, venueList);
            fillList(date, dateList);
            fillList(ticket, ticketList);
            fillList(price, priceList);
            break;
    }
}

function fillList(list,items) {
    list.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var option = new Option(items[i]);
        list.options[i] = option;
    }   
}
```

Comment: and where does the fillList(list,items) part relate to?

Comment: Updated the code. What do you mean where does `fillList` relate to?

Comment: How do i now use this code to calculate the number of tickets by price asnd display to user? @akinuri

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, You can retrieve value of any Drop Down using:

```
var selectedId = $('#DD_1 option:selected').val();
```

and Set value of a drop down like this:

```
$('#DD_2[value=' + selectedId + ']').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: I need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

After checking you updated question i have created a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/paXz9/1/

It is working fine.

Try following code:

```
   var names = document.getElementsByName("sel");
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i].onchange = function() {

       val = this.value;
        var allSelect = document.getElementsByName("sel");
        for (var j = 0; j < allSelect.length; j++) {
        allSelect[j].value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

See in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/JrpR6/1/